# How to make the path public in RSocketSecurity(Spring)

Tags: spring, kotlin, rsocket, spring-rsocket

I have config class for RSocketSecurity
Something like that

```
@Configuration
@EnableRSocketSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
class RSocketAuthConfiguration {
```

and authorization for it (allows only authenticated users to subscribe )

```
     security.addPayloadInterceptor(interceptor).authorizePayload {
        it.setup().authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll()
    }
```

I want to set some routes with public access, but most of them should be with authorization. What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security Rsocket configures the `setup` and `route` respectively.

The following is an example of the configuration part.

```java
@Bean
public PayloadSocketAcceptorInterceptor rsocketInterceptor(RSocketSecurity rsocket) {
        return rsocket
                .authorizePayload(
                        authorize -> {
                            authorize
                                    // must have ROLE_SETUP to make connection
                                    .setup().hasRole("SETUP")
                                    // must have ROLE_ADMIN for routes starting with "greet."
                                    .route("greet*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                                    // any other request must be authenticated for
                                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
                        }
                )
                .basicAuthentication(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
```

Get [the complete example](https://github.com/hantsy/rsocket-sample/blob/master/security) from my Github.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the following lines should work:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableRSocketSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
class RSocketSecurityConfiguration(val authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {

    @Bean
    fun authorization(security: RSocketSecurity): PayloadSocketAcceptorInterceptor {
        return security
                .authorizePayload {
                    it.route("route-A").hasRole("role-A")
                        .route("route-B").permitAll()
                }
                .simpleAuthentication(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationService)
                .build()
    }
}
```

`route-A` is authenticated and requires `role-A` while `route-B` is publicly available.